# How to drop rows by threshold of index column's occur frequence in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
userid itemid timestamp
  1       1      50
  1       2      50
  1       3      50
  1       4      60
  2       1      40
  2       2      50
```

I want to drop all rows whose userid occur more than 2 times and get a new dataframe as follows. Does someone can help me? Thanks.

```
userid itemid timestamp
  2       1      40
  2       2      50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.value_counts` and calculate an array of `userid` filtered by your condition. Then use this to filter your original dataframe.

```
c = df['userid'].value_counts()
idx = c[c > 2].index

res = df[~df['userid'].isin(idx)]

print(res)

   userid  itemid  timestamp
4       2       1         40
5       2       2         50
```

Comment: s = [k for k in df['userid'].value_counts().keys() 
if df['userid'].value_counts()[k] <= 2]

df[(df['userid'].isin(s))]

Comment: I have try method above, it was very slow, yours is much quicker. Thanks.